# How to use $.each with ajax to get JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using ajax to get JSON from an API, however I am having a problem, retrieving the data. The code for ajax function is fine as I am using it elsewhere. I believe that the issue is with the `.done(function()`.

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:4001/Barratt/getData.php",
            //dataType: 'json',
            //method: 'GET',
            //contentType: 'application/json'
            data: {url: developmentURL},
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //var developments = [];
            $.each(data, function() {
                $.each(this, function(i, obj) {
                    console.log(i, obj.Name + ' = ' + obj.ItemKey);
                    //developments.push();
                });
            });
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Failed to fetch data')
        });
```

This is the code I am using, which just logs loads of `0 "undefined=undefined"`. However I have the `.done(function()` working in a jsfiddle, with the JSON hard coded. So I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejrvpe7m/)

Comment: please show the data structure returned

Comment: Create a dummy json structure in http://beta.json-generator.com
and change the url from your or share the json link from json-generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` is of string type. Parse the string into JSON before looping:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data, function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `JSON.parse` you can Set the `dataType` to just 'json' and you will automatically recieve a parsed json response:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:4001/Barratt/getData.php",
        dataType: 'json', //Uncomment this line
        //method: 'GET',
        //contentType: 'application/json'
        data: {
            url: developmentURL
        },
        method: 'POST'
    })
```

Or you can also make use of jquery `$.getJSON` api.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the data that you retrive is an array of Json according to your code.
You forgot add key and value in the $.each callback function to loop into each Json value.

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:4001/Barratt/getData.php",
            //dataType: 'json',
            //method: 'GET',
            //contentType: 'application/json'
            data: {url: developmentURL},
            method: 'POST'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            //var developments = [];
            $.each(data, function(key,value) {
                $.each(value, function(subKey, subValue) {
                    console.log(subKey, subValue.Name + ' = ' + subValue.ItemKey);
                    //developments.push();
                });
            });
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert('Failed to fetch data')
        });
```